# How to use "Spread syntax"(...) and "Conditional operator"( ? : ) at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let a = [1, 2];
let b = [3, 4];
let c = 5;
let d = [...a, ...b]; // OK
let e = [...a, (c === 5 ? (...b) : 3)]; // error info: Expression expected
```

I think ***e*** should be [1, 2, 3, 4], however I got error message, could anyone explain why?

(I tried in IDE and Chrome console, with or without parentheses, same error message.)

Comment: The screenshot is distracting and adds no new information. Plain-text code is better for a lot of reasons, primarily readability and reusability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to tadman's answer: Think about what `...b` is, it is just the numbers spread out as "3, 4". You could not assign that to a variable, i.e. `const spreadB = ...b // spreadB = 3, 4` will not compile. As already answered, you need to move the spread operator up a level.

```
    // This is why it does not work
    // const spreadB: number[] = ...b; // what is "3, 4"; it is not [3, 4]
    const spreadB: number[] = [...b]; // now it is an array

    // The type of your ternary expression is a number[] (since the lhs is an array
    const ternaryAsArray: number[] = (c === 5 ? [...b]: [3]);
    const e: number[] = [...a, ...ternaryAsArray];
```

Comment: Thanks, So the reason is that (...[1, 2]) is not an expression ?

MDN docs show that in "A ? B : C", B and C must be expressions, the error msg "Expression expected" means IDE thinks that (...X) is not an expression.

A little confusing, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to kick the `...` up a level:

```js
let e = [ ...a, ...(c === 5 ? b : [ 3 ])];
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, I understand this is ok, but I do not know why my code does not work.
I checked MDN docs and still do not find the reason.

Comment: If this is a TypeScript question that's fine, but do tag it as well so we can recommend accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
let e = [...a, ... c === 5 ? b : [3]];
```